# Redirect system2 stdout to a file on windows

Tags: r, stdout, cran, devtools, system2

According to the [manual](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system2.html), the `stdout` argument of the `system2` function can redirect output to a file. This seems to work on unix, however I can't get it to work on windows. The toy example below, no `out.txt` or `err.txt` files are created. I tried sending it to an existing file, or expand the full file path, but with no success:

```
setwd(tempdir())
system2("whoami", stdout="out.txt", stderr="err.txt")
file.exists("out.txt")
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a limitation in `system2` ?

Comment: Your snippet shows `system()`, not `system2()`. Typo?

Comment: Good question. `system2` doesn't seem to be behaving as advertised. Especially given that the Windows and UNIX versions of `system2` are implemented using different source code, you'd think this difference in behavior (if intended) would be mentioned in `?system2`.

Comment: OK in that case I'll move it to `r-devel`.

Comment: Thanks. [Uwe Ligges here mentions](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-November/258381.html) that portability was the motivation for creating `system2()`, so this is presumably a discrepancy R-core will care about. (FWIW, I just tried Grothendieck's proposed fix (from R-devel), and it doesn't work for me, running an up-to-date R on Windows XP...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite convinced now this is a bug in RGui.exe in windows. I filed a bug report here: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=15393

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Had [the same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18080378/684229).