# tm readPDF: Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r, tm, pdf-scraping

I have tried the [example code recommended in the tm::readPDF documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/tm/docs/readPDF):

```
library(tm)

if(all(file.exists(Sys.which(c("pdfinfo", "pdftotext"))))) {
    uri <- system.file(file.path("doc", "tm.pdf"), package = "tm")
    pdf <- readPDF(PdftotextOptions = "-layout")(elem = list(uri = uri),
                                                 language = "en",
                                                 id = "id1")
    pdf[1:13]
}
```

But I get the following error (which occurs after calling the function returned by `readPDF`):

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'C:\DOCUME~1\Tomas\LOCALS~1\Temp\RtmpU33iWo\pdfinfo31c2bd5762a': No such file or directory
```

Note that I have installed all xpdf binaries to current directory (but this is handled by the `if` condition).

**EDIT: found out this is a bug. What would be the easiest workaround?**

Comment: Easy workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979074/error-trying-to-read-a-pdf-using-readpdf-from-the-tm-package/17981259#17981259

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did some debugging and see it fails in `tm:::pdfinfo()`:

```
status <- system2("pdfinfo", shQuote(normalizePath(file)), 
        stdout = outfile)
```

This command doesn't create the outfile. According to [Redirect system2 stdout to a file on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638090/redirect-system2-stdout-to-a-file-on-windows) this is a bug!